# How to generate unique channel name for every user in agora.io Java?

Tags: java, android, agora.io

I am developing an live video broadcasting app in android java using agora.io services.
Problem is here agora.io provide a specific channel name but I need a unique channel name for a specific user. So question is that how to generate a unique channel name so every user can connect with a specific channel name.
if any one know best option then agora.io for live video broadcasting sdk or api in android java.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need to need to do these logics in the backend.